# Как пробежаться по директориям внутри цикла?

Tags: bash, shell

Хочу сделать что-то вроде:

```
for d in список_всех_вложенных_директорий ;
do
  cd d ;
  for f in *.tif ; do mogrify -опции "$f" ; done ;
  cd .. ;
done
```

Как обратиться ко всем директориям поочередно в теле цикла?

Знания баша почти нулевые, если что-то фундаментальное попутал - объясните.

Comment: Всем спасибо, благодаря вам все заработало.

Comment: отметь, пожалуйста, полезные ответы

Comment: Репутацию мне изменять пока не дают, а в комментариях всплывает совет не писать неинформативно. Или как-то по-другому отметить?

А вообще твой был первым, что помог, и самым понятным; вариант с чистым find тоже оказался весьма неплох - сейчас его использую, т.к. меньше текста; а вариант с записью в тмп ближе всего к тому, что я "заказывал", но я не особо понял, как он работает.

P.S. Понял, ты про галки...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in `find . -type f -name '*.tif'`; do
    mogrify -опции $f ;
done ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Выведет все директории в `/tmp`

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in /tmp/*/
do
    dir=${dir%*/}
    echo ${dir##*/}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

find сам себя крутить умеет. Достаточно

```
find . -name '*.tif' -execdir mogrify -опции {} \;
```